# How to get path from URL in warp?

Tags: rust, rust-warp

I am using `warp` to build a Proxy. The proxy doesn't care about parameters or path, it just delegate requests from clients. So the client may query like:

`https://proxy.com/p1?a=1&b=2` or
`https://proxy.com/p2?c=1` or many other different paths

I want to write something like this:

```
    /*
    client query: https://proxy.com/test_path1?a=1
    client query: https://proxy.com/test_path2?b=2
     */
    let filter = warp::any()
        .and(warp::query::<HashMap<String, String>>())
        .map(|p: HashMap<String, String>| {
            let path = xxx.get_path();  // path = "/test_path1" or "/test_path2"
            println!("{:?}",p); // p = {"a":1} or {"b":2} respectively
        });
```

instead of this:

```
    let path1 = warp::path("test_path1").and(warp::query::<HashMap<String, String>>()).map(|p: HashMap<String,String>|{
        let path = "test_path1".to_string();
        println!("{:?}",p); // p = {"a":1} or {"b":2} respectively
    });

    let path2 = warp::path("test_path2").and(warp::query::<HashMap<String, String>>()).map(|p: HashMap<String,String>|{
        let path = "test_path2".to_string();
        println!("{:?}",p); // p = {"a":1} or {"b":2} respectively
    });
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

Without any further detail, this does what you want by utilizing the [`full`](https://docs.rs/warp/latest/warp/filters/path/fn.full.html) filter:

```
use warp::{self, path::FullPath, Filter};

let filter = warp::any()
    .and(warp::query::<HashMap<String, String>>())
    .and(warp::path::full())
    .map(|q: HashMap<_, _>, p: FullPath| {
        let path = p.as_str();
        format!("path: {}\nquery: {:?}", path, q)
    });
```

Comment: How do you guys find it in the document, is it there some special methodology? I was wondering.

Comment: Luckily, warp's docs are very well structured. Something like this will definitely be a filter, so I went looking in the `warp::filter` module and because it deals with the path of a request, I reckoned that it'll probably be in the `path` module. Then I just went look ing through the functions until something caught my eye, in this case "`full`: Returns the full request path, irrespective of other filters."

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.rs/warp/latest/warp/filters/path/fn.tail.html

But are you even using `warp::any`? That's useful as a base to BYO (e.g. to add external data to the request) but `warp::query` is a filter, if you're using only that it doesn't need to be chained to anything.

And HTTP allows repeating query parameters so technically if you reify to a hashmap there is no guarantee the "proxy" will fully replicate the original request.

Comment: "there is no guarantee the "proxy" will fully replicate the original request", does it means something like `proxy.com/path1/{int32}/{int32}?a=1`? Can you give an example?

Comment: `a=1&a=2` is a valid query string, and depending on the target can mean that `a` is a sequence of values.